# How do you repeat a macro in Komodo Edit?

Tags: komodoedit

In many other editors, when you record a macro you can run that macro repeatedly.  However, in Komodo Edit there is not an option to do so.  In Komodo Edit, how do you repeat a macro X times, or repeat a macro to the end of a file?

[image: NotePad++ lets you repeat a macro]

*NotePad++ lets you repeat a macro*

[image: Komodo Edit doesn't have that option in the menu]

*Komodo Edit doesn't have that option in the menu*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it in a macro (I call mine "Run current macro to end of file"):

```
var currentMacro = ko.macros.recorder.currentMacro;
if (!currentMacro || !currentMacro.length) {
    alert("There is no current macro to execute");
    return;
}
var view = ko.views.manager.currentView;
var scimoz = view.scimoz;
var startingLine = scimoz.lineFromPosition(scimoz.currentPos);
var i = 1;
scimoz.beginUndoAction();
try {
    while (true) {
        ko.macros.recorder.executeLastMacro();
        let newPos = scimoz.currentPos;
        let newLine = scimoz.lineFromPosition(newPos);
        if (newLine <= startingLine) {
            newLine = startingLine + 1;
        }
        startingLine = newLine;
        if (startingLine >= scimoz.lineCount) {
            break;
        }
        scimoz.gotoPos(scimoz.positionFromLine(startingLine));
    }
} finally {
    scimoz.endUndoAction();
}
```

You can also have macros invoke other macros, but that's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat a macro X amount of times by using the "Code > Repeat Next Keystroke N Times" menu item. There is no option to repeat the current macro until the end of the file, however an enhancement request has been logged for this (which I've just bumped and hope to see in our next major release): http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=76022

Answer (score 1):

First record a macro. (with single action).
Edit the source code of macro (using JavaScript or Python)
Example: **Text File**
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc

**Recorded macro code:**

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(3);
if (komodo.view) {
    komodo.view.setFocus();
}
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_home')
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_right')
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_right')
    komodo.view.selection = ' - ';
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_lineNext')
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_home')
```

Now we can loop (9 times in this case) or run till the end of file as shown by Eric, by **editing code** as follows:

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(3);
if (komodo.view) {
    komodo.view.setFocus();
}

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_home')
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_right')
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_right')
    komodo.view.selection = ' - ';
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_lineNext')
    ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_home')    
}
```

**For reference**: http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/macroapi.html